# showing almost convergence of product of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\left(X_j\right)_{j \geq 1}$ be i.i.d. positive with $\log X_j \in \mathrm{L}^4$. Prove that $\left(\prod_{j=1}^n X_j\right)^{1 / n}$ converges almost surely as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Does it converge in distribution?

I tried using if $ \forall \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{n}-X|> \epsilon) < \infty $, then $X_{n}$ converge almost surely to $X$ idea, but since I couldn't guess limit, I can't also proceed, putting 0 as limit is causing problem, once I apply Markov to each expression

Comment: Hint: $\ln\left(\prod_{j=1}^n X_j\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \ln(X_j)$ and $\ln(X_j) \in L^4$ so also $\ln(X_j) \in L^1$.

Comment: so, we apply strong law of large number?

Comment: @noidea The assumption about $L^4$ kind of hints that you should try it. Other than that, fourth moment is rarely assumed about random variables. Make sure that you check all the other conditions though. (for example that the logarithms are independent)

Comment: @DominikKutek The strong law for i.i.d random variables in $L^1$ is a nontrivial result though. Maybe OP is only familiar with the result for i.id random variables in $L^4$, which has a much more simple proof. (which is why the $L^4$ assumption)

Comment: Thank you..I got the answer, we can do power 4 expansion and do same thing as I was doing above,,i just need to centered random variable and proceed which I was not doing.